# Short term access token does not expire

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-web-api, oauth-2.0, access-token

**Description**

In my ASP.NET web application, for debugging purposes, I have set the access token expire time to 15 seconds.

However, it seems that the token is still valid after 15 seconds.

```
OAuthOptions = new OAuthAuthorizationServerOptions
{
    TokenEndpointPath = new PathString("/Token"),
    Provider = new ApplicationOAuthProvider(PublicClientId),
    AuthorizeEndpointPath = new PathString("/api/v1/Account/ExternalLogin"),

    #if DEBUG                
            AccessTokenExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(15),
    #else
            AccessTokenExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromDays(12),
    #endif

};
```

**Note**

I've tested this both in my web application and also via *Postman* (a Google chrome extension for creating REST requests.) as below:

1. I obtain a token by sending a `POST` to the *Token* endpoint.
2. Add this token in the *Authorization* header of the Http request as: `"Bearer + {token}"`.
3. I send a request to `GET` a page which requires authentication.

Result: always can access the page. (after 15 seconds).

**Question**

I was wondering if there is a minimum value for the token expiration?

Why is this happening?

Comment: What does your API controller look like?

Comment: @Ali aside from using the OAuth bearer token, do you also happen to have cookie authentication (`UseCookieAuthentication`) enabled?

Comment: @IronGeek yes it's enabled. (I think that explains why)

Comment: Yes, by default the cookie expiration is set to [14 days](http://katanaproject.codeplex.com/sourcecontrol/latest#src/Microsoft.Owin.Security.Cookies/CookieAuthenticationOptions.cs). For custom expiration time, you need to change the `ExpireTimeSpan` property on the [`CookieAuthenticationOptions`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.owin.security.cookies.cookieauthenticationoptions.aspx). You might also need to change the `SlidingExpiration` value to `false`.

Comment: @IronGeek However when I test it with Postman, I dont set any cookies.

Comment: Postman does set cookies from a response. And unfortunately, if you happen to use the [packaged app](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/postman/fhbjgbiflinjbdggehcddcbncdddomop) version of Postman, [there's no easy way to remove it](https://github.com/postmanlabs/postman-app-support/issues/1228). To verify this you can write: `var cookies = Request.Headers.GetCookies()` anywhere in the controller's action, and see if there's any cookie sent.